# When are the Eigenvectors of a A and $A^T$ the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A$ which has distinct, real eigenvalues. Will $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvectors. I thought this result was false, but I am reading a paper which uses this as a fact when $A$ is a $2\times 2$ real matrix.

Comment: It is indeed false. Check $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for example.

Comment: Is the paper taking the transpose of the eigenvectors as well as the transpose of the matrix?

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. Deleting my previous comments because they are misleading.

Comment: @MarkBennet it is missing steps but the result seems to imply that it will need this fact to be true. It involves transforming a strictly hyperbolic pde to get a decoupled pair of pdes

Comment: This seems strange, but *eigenvalues* are indeed equal, maybe authors just mixed it somehow? For eigenvectors, right eigenvectors of $A^t$ are left eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: @PeterFranek it turns out the author stated that they were left eigenvectors and I just read that they were eigenvectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the hypothesis that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvectors iff $A$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) ($A^T A = A A^T$), and with the further hypothesis that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues iff $A$ is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) ($A^T = A$). So any non-symmetric matrix with real distinct eigenvalues is a counterexample; in the $2 \times 2$ case we can take, for example,

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{array} \right].$$

$A$ has eigenvectors $v_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} -1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$ and $v_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$. Its transpose

$$A^T = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 3 \end{array} \right]$$

has the same eigenvalues but eigenvectors $w_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right], w_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$.

You'll notice in the above example that $v_1$ is orthogonal to $w_2$ and vice versa. This generalizes: if $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and $w_j$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j \neq \lambda_i$, then

$$w_j^T A v_i = w_j^T (\lambda v_i) = \lambda_i w_j^T v_i$$

but we also have

$$w_j^T A v_i = (A w_j)^T v_i = (\lambda_j w_j)^T v_i = \lambda_j w_j^T v_i$$

which gives $w_j^T v_i = 0$. This says that if $A$ has distinct real eigenvalues then the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^T$ are dual bases with respect to the inner product (up to scale), which among other things is one way to prove the above result: if the eigenvectors of $A$ aren't orthogonal then they can't be their own dual basis.

Comment: Is it true that: "$A$ and $B$ (with distinct real eigenvalues same as $A$) have the same eigenvectors iff $B A = A B$"? I think the the last equality holds iff $B=A^k$ for some $k$. (so in case $B=A^T$ it should be $B=A^k$. isn't?)

Comment: The first statement is true but the second isn't. Any polynomial in $A$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: I actually meant that. $P(A)=I+aA+...$. So $A^T$ is a polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Yes, for a matrix with distinct eigenvalues that's equivalent, but normality is much easier to check!